# Spring integration MessageTransformationException failed to transform message

Tags: amqp, spring-integration

I'm trying to run this (https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/wgrus/tree/master/spring-integration) wgrus sample application using spring integration v2.2.6.RELEASE and keep getting a MessageTransformationException. The application is split into 3 components - a store UI, an inventory service and a shipping service (this service is irrelevant here) and uses the AMQP protocol to send messages to RabbitMQ. In brief, you enter order details in the UI and send them to an order channel in the form of a message. Behind the scenes the application performs a claim check, which stores the message in Mongo (I can see that it gets stored) and returns a new message, whose payload is the id of the stored message - so far so good, the message is stored and I can see the amqpOut channel returning the Id of the stored message, i.e. 826bcbfb-21fa-424d-aecd-0bab3d1a690b - this can be seen in the debug shown at the bottom of my question. Next, the message is sent to RabbitMQ through an outbound AMQP channel and is supposed to be picked up by the inventory service and at this point the exception is thrown. I can see that at some point something happens with the id of the stored message as the debug prints `Payload=???sr?java.util.UUID????m?/`

Has anyone come across this issue and knows how to resolve it?

Config used by the store UI:

```
<int:object-to-json-transformer input-channel="orderChannel" output-channel="jsonOrders" content-type="text/x-json"/>

<int:claim-check-in input-channel="jsonOrders" output-channel="amqpOut" message-store="messageStore"/>

<amqp:outbound-channel-adapter id="amqpOut" amqp-template="rabbitTemplate" routing-key="orders"/>
...
```

Config used by the inventory service:

```
<int:claim-check-out message-store="messageStore" input-channel="orderChannel" output-channel="inventoryChannel" remove-message="true" />

<amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="orderChannel"
  connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"
  queue-names="orders"
  error-channel="errorLogger" />

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="errorLogger" log-full-message="true" level="INFO"/>

<int:chain input-channel="inventoryChannel" output-channel="amqpOut">
  <int:json-to-object-transformer type="org.wgrus.Order"/>
  <int:enricher request-channel="creditCheck">
    <int:property name="approved" expression="payload.startsWith('OK')"/>
  </int:enricher>
  <int:enricher request-channel="inventoryRouter">
    <int:property name="reserved" expression="payload"/>
  </int:enricher>
  <int:object-to-json-transformer content-type="text/x-json" />
  <int:claim-check-in/>
</int:chain>
...
```

DEBUG:

> DEBUG: http-bio-8080-exec-3
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - postSend
>   (sent=true) on channel 'amqpOut', message:
>   [Payload=826bcbfb-21fa-424d-aecd-0bab3d1a690b][Headers={timestamp=1384617973920,
>   id=e98cd0c1-bd8c-4786-be31-1e77b0200934, content-type=text/x-json}]
>
> DEBUG: http-bio-8080-exec-3
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - postSend
>   (sent=true) on channel 'jsonOrders', message:
>   [Payload={"id":1,"approved":false,"reserved":false,"customerId":"","quantity":1,"productId":"widget"}][Headers={timestamp=1384617973852,
>   id=826bcbfb-21fa-424d-aecd-0bab3d1a690b, content-type=text/x-json}]
>
> DEBUG: http-bio-8080-exec-3
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - postSend
>   (sent=true) on channel 'orderChannel', message: [Payload=Order #1: 1
>   widgets for ][Headers={timestamp=1384617973824,
>   id=1b700a4b-35e1-4d16-8ca0-7cd20ccfb85e}]
>
> DEBUG:
>   SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1
>   org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper -
>   headerName=[content-type] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=content-type
>
> DEBUG: SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1
>   org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper -
>   headerName=[amqp_receivedRoutingKey] WILL be mapped, matched
>   pattern=amqp_receivedRoutingKey
>
> DEBUG: SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1
>   org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper -
>   headerName=[amqp_deliveryMode] WILL be mapped, matched
>   pattern=amqp_deliveryMode
>
> DEBUG: SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1
>   org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper -
>   headerName=[amqp_redelivered] WILL be mapped, matched
>   pattern=amqp_redelivered
>
> DEBUG: SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1
>   org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper -
>   headerName=[amqp_deliveryTag] WILL be mapped, matched
>   pattern=amqp_deliveryTag
>
> DEBUG: SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1
>   org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper -
>   headerName=[content-type] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=content-type
>
> DEBUG: SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on
>   channel 'orderChannel', message:
>   [Payload=???sr?java.util.UUID????m?/?J?leastSigBitsJ?mostSigBitsxp???=i?k??!?][Headers={timestamp=1384617974260,
>   id=81a2fb77-0f1e-4be7-9148-84da86a30ed8, content-type=text/x-json,
>   amqp_receivedRoutingKey=orders, amqp_deliveryMode=PERSISTENT,
>   amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_deliveryTag=1}]
>
> DEBUG: SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1
>   org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler
>   - org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler#1
>   received message: [Payload=???sr?java.util.UUID????m?/?J?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your issue is here:

```
<int:object-to-json-transformer input-channel="orderChannel" output-channel="jsonOrders" content-type="text/x-json"/>
```

Can you explain what is the reason to set `content-type`, if you after that use `<claim-check-in>`, who just return `UUID` - id of the stored Message?

And what is happened?

Your `UUID` is convert to serialized bytes by `SimpleMessageConverter` and this converter sets 
`contentType` as `application/x-java-serialized-object` to the `MessageProperties`. 
But after that is called `AmqpHeaderMapper`, who changes `contentType` with your value `text/x-json` from `MessageHeaders`.
That's fine for Producer.

But Consumer can't convert the Body correctly, because here also works `SimpleMessageConverter` by default.
And it checks `contentType.startsWith("text")`.
And just create simple String from bytes of serialized `UUID`.

Hope it is clear

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately `<object-to-json-transformer>` sets `content-type` header anyway, to `application/json` by default.

To prevent it you should configure like this `content-type=""`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. In response to your question: **Can you explain what is the reason to set content-type, if you after that use <claim-check-in>, who just return UUID - id of the stored Message?**
Having read the "Important" part of section 6 here [http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#transformer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#transformer) I was under the impression that content-type needs to be set in my case.

Comment: I was under the impression that content type has to be set when using spring integration version 2.2 in order to resolve the MessageTransformationException, which I was also getting before setting the content-type attribute. I've now removed the content type again to confirm I still get the same exception (I still get it). I'd be grateful if you could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I added one more option to my answer